# Trailing comma in a type

Tags: scala, types

What the heck is the following type:

```
(Int, => Double) => String
```

Note the trailing comma after `Int`. Apparently it is not a syntactic loophole, but something different from

```
(Int => Double) => String
```

E.g. when using overloading:

```
trait Foo {
  def bar(x: (Int, => Double) => String): Unit
  def bar(x: (Int  => Double) => String): Unit
}
```

Comment: Why did you think it was a trailing comma instead of a separator comma?

Comment: Good question, I guess you need to ask a gestalt theorist...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`(Int, => Double) => String` is a function with by-name second argument (`=> Double`).

You can't create a `Function2[Int, => Double, String]`, but you could create a lambda `(Int, => Double) => String`, that means the same:

```
scala> def s:(Int, => Double) => String =
     |   (a, b) => if (a > 0) a.toString else b.toString
s: (Int, => Double) => String

scala> s(1, {println("test"); 2.0}) //second parameter is not evaluated
res0: String = 1

scala> s(-1, {println("test"); 2.0})
test
res1: String = 2.0
```